# Life cycle of a fragment - turn off and on the screen

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, lifecycle

So I have a question that might be obvious but I have seen many answers on the Internet. As I am a newbie in Java for Android, I am asking for some help here.

So I have a fragment A. Inside this fragment, I can tap on a button to search by bluetooth some devices (namely thermal printers). When it has found one then it creates a fragment B with the settings of the device.

When I search for the first time, I find one device, I can see the fragment B inside the fragment A. **But when I turn off the screen and then I turn on the screen the fragment B disappears.** I am still trying to understand why.

**So I am wondering what happens in the life cycle of a fragment when we turn off and turn on the screen** (not the phone, just the screen).

When I look at the android doc, I thought that : 
*turn off screen -> OnDestroyView()*, then the others (onActivityCreated(), onStart(), onResume() ).
*turn on screen -> On CreateView()*

But I have heard other answers.... so I am not sure now.

If someone can help me, thank you in advance.

**Edit** : the fragment B is inside a `ViewPager`. The `ViewPager` is inside the Fragment A

Comment: some code around how the view pager is configured and how does FragmentA launch the FragmentB?

Comment: Finally it's okey, I have a "solution". I realised that every time I turn off and turn on the screen, android kills the fragment once (so it calls onDestroy() and so on). And then it tries to create a fragment again (onCreateView() to onResume() ). My problem was in these steps of recreation, I didn't force android to get data drom the database, so I force to do it inside onResume(). So now it's okey